# Text overflow ellipsis adds unknown character at the end

Tags: flutter, ellipsis, text-rendering

I use custom font Inter for my Flutter Web project. And in all Text widgets with ellipsis I got unknown symbol at the end of text. When font changed to Roboto problem disappears. What the symbol inserts into the text by flatter engine? I cant event select text and debug, because of text renders on canvas. PS: SelectableText cant be ellipsis:)

[image]

Comment: Did you managed to solve this issue?

Comment: @IosifPop yes, by using default framework's font...

Comment: Thank you! Since I commented here I found [the github issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/76473) if you want to subscribe to it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of canvas use html renderer, solved the problem for me.
Use

```
flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer html
```

for building.

Instead of this option you could also change you font. GoogleFonts should work fine.